# how can i stop a while loop upon a integer variable getting a value?

Tags: java, while-loop

How can I stop a while loop from looping when an integer variable gets a value. By value I mean any value not just a predefined value.

`int foo;
while(foo = ){
    // some code
    }`

right when foo gets value i would like the while loop to stop.

Comment: you [`break;`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Comment: `while (foo != value) {`

Comment: Uh, you wouldn't be able to use `foo` if it were not initialized (which means it already has a value)! Please reword your question more clearly

Comment: If that other value is in the variable `target`, have `while (foo != target) {...}`

Comment: We need a bit more context on that. Perhaps it is better to run the loop until it is *possible* to set the value of foo, then set the value of foo after we know we are ready to break out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I exit a while loop in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951690/how-do-i-exit-a-while-loop-in-java)

Comment: Is it going to stop if foo is 0? Is 0 a valid "value"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Maybe the Java tutorials would be a good port of call here, particularly the section on loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am interpreting "By value I mean any value not just a predefined value" as that you want the loop to break as soon as `foo` gets any sort of value.

Due to the rules of local variables, any assignment to `foo` *must* cause `foo` to get a value (it being primitive, namely int).

Therefore, either no loop actually will happen and you simply assign `foo`, or you'll have some conditional that when taken assigns `foo`. The former is a trivial case of assigning to foo. The latter can be written as:

```
int foo = 0; //dummy value
while (true){ 
  if (/*ready to assign*/){
       foo = /*whatever value you assign to it*/
       break;
    }
}
```

The dummy value is used as compilers don't do very much static analysis and may complain about the value being uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
int foo = 0;
while (foo != value) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: "By value I mean any value not just a predefined value." I think he wants to have it uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

```
while(foo != ...) {
    foo = ...
}
```

When foo reaches the value you'd like, the loop will finish.

```
while(true) {
    foo = ...
    if(foo = ...) {
        break;
     }
 }
```

This loop will *always* continue unless `foo` reaches the value you'd like to exit on. `break` will exit any loop, so in this case when `foo` equals your value, it will exit.